# Using Linq to perform CRUD on SETS: how to?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, linq-to-entities, crud

Using Linq, trying to select all records not in my local set fails:

```
var localset = new List<Category>();
localset.Add( new Category { pk1 = 1, pk2 = 1, name = "one" } );
localset.Add( new Category { pk1 = 1, pk2 = 2, name = "two" } );

var dbCategories = dc.Categories;

var diff = dbCategories.Except(localset);
```

I need to do basic CRUD: delete from the db set when not in my local set, update where exists, and add new when not there.

I would normally do:

```
delete from Category C where not exists
    ( select null from LocalSet L where C.pk1 = L.pk1 and C.pk2 = L.pk2 )

update Category set name = L.name
from LocalSet L
where L.pk1 = Category.pk1 and L.pk2 = Category.pk2

insert into Category (pk1, pk2, name)
select pk1, pk2, name
from LocalSet L
where not exists (
    select null from Category C where L.pk1 = C.pk1 and L.pk2 = C.pk2 )
```

Easy enough I thought.  However, .Contains seems to be the only method that works with local sets, and it only seems to compare a single field.  The database table has composite keys.

Without changing the composite keys, is there any way to accomplish these tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to implement a `CategoryComparer` like the following:

```
public class CategoryComparer : IEqualityComparer<Category>
{
    public bool Equals(Category a, Category b)
    {
        bool result = false;
        if( a.pk1 == b.pk1 && a.pk2 == b.pk2 && a.name == b.name)
            result = true;
        return result;    
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Category category)
    {        
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(category, null)) return 0;        
        return category.pk1.GetHashCode() ^ category.pk2.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then call Enumerable.Except:

```
var localset = new List<Category>();
localset.Add( new Category { pk1 = 1, pk2 = 1, name = "one" } );
localset.Add( new Category { pk1 = 1, pk2 = 2, name = "two" } );

var diff = dc.Categories
             .AsEnumerable()
             .Except(localset, new CategoryComparer());
```

Let me know if this gets you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me which Contains method you're talking about, I'm afraid... but a *general* solution to using composite keys is to make a single value using an anonymous type.

For example, if you want to *join* on compound keys, you might use

```
from x in xs
join y in ys on new { x.k1, x.k2 } equals new { y.k1, y.k2 }
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

What about doing this:

```
var localset = new List<Category>();
localset.Add(new Category { pk1 = 1, pk2 = 1, name = "one" });
localset.Add(new Category { pk1 = 1, pk2 = 2, name = "two" });

var flattened = localset
    .Select(dd => dd.pk1 + "|" + dd.pk2 + "|" + dd.name)
    .ToArray();

var dbCategories = dc.Categories;

var diff = from c in dbCategories
           let x = c.pk1 + "|" + c.pk2 + "|" + c.name
           where !flattened.Contains(x)
           select c;
```

This converts a composite key into a single array that allows you to use the `Contains` operator. Let me know if it helps. Cheers.